# column size in the table automatically created by Grails

Tags: grails

If this has been answered already, I apologize for not looking, as I did some search but could not find the answer here..

I just started reading "Grails in Action" book today, and I am testing the Quote application in chapter 1. At some point, we add constraint to the domain class to make the content column to be of size 1000 (if I understand correctly) like:

```
static constraints = {

    author(blank : false)
    **content(maxsize:1000, blank:false)**
}
```

Does this mean, the column will be automatically changed from VARCHAR(255) to VARCHAR(1000)? If so, does it happen after restarting the app? Because it does not seem to be the case for me.  Please help me understand and thanks for your time!

Comment: Grails 2.x is slightly better at modifying the schema.  But I'd highly recommend the database-migration plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, maxSize should change the schema definition of the table (note: not all the constraints do this).

Try to change the dbCreate property in the DataSource.groovy file. Maybe it is set to update and Grails is unable to alter the table, so it has to recreate it completely, for that you can try with `create`, but keep in mind that the table will be dropped so it can have the new schema.

Comment: Just using 'create' won't cause a drop.  You would have to do 'drop-create'.

Comment: is `create-drop`, and `create` alone does cause a drop. You can read about that in the [docs](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/conf.html#dataSource) ."create - Drops the existing schemaCreates the schema on startup, dropping existing tables, indexes, etc. first."
"create-drop - Same as create, but also drops the tables when the application shuts down cleanly."